# inserting multiple values from source table to destination table

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

will the below code will take all the values from src table and insert into IC_MST_VELOCITY table. I need to know how to take all the records from src table to IC_MST_VELOCITY table if the below code is wrong.

```
       (SELECT  ARTICLE,
                CONCATKEY,
                CAST (LASTMODIFIEDDATE AS TIMESTAMP)   AS LASTMOD,
                PRODSUBGRP,
                FROM IC_VELOCITY_V 
                ) src

    INSERT INTO IC_MST_VELOCITY(
                                ARTICLE,
                                CONCATKEY,
                                ISDELETED,
                                LASTMODIFIEDDATE,
                                MSTID,
                                PRODSUBGRP,
                                SKUID,
                                VELOCITY,
                                WHSE) 
                    VALUES(
                    select ARTICLE    from src,
                    select CONCATKEY  from src,
                    select LASTMOD    from src,
                    select PRODSUBGRP from src,
                 )

                    );
```

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure for this? You can use an `insert into ... select ...` statement ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423__GUID-1DB0B423-DC07-4B3C-B1CA-C836DF43272A)) as a single operation; I guess you could still wrap that in PL/SQL if that is a requirement but it isn't necessary.

Comment: Can you review your Question, I think you are missing some important piece of information while asking?
I feel you can refer examples of Bulk Collect if you have huge records to insert data.
Also can use `Insert into A
select * from B where 1=1`

Answer (score 0):

No, your code wouldn't do anything as it is invalid.

Something like this might; note all `NULL` values being inserted into columns that don't have the *source* value (selected from the `ic_velocity_v` table):

```
insert into ic_mst_velocity
  ( article,
    concatkey,
    isdeleted,
    lastmodifieddate,
    mstid,
    prodsubgrp,
    skuid,
    velocity,
    whse
  ) 
  (select article,
          concatkey,
          null isdeleted,
          cast(lastmodifieddate as timestamp) as lastmod,
          null mstid, 
          prodsubgrp,
          null skuid,
          null velocity,
          null whse
   from ic_velocity_v
  );
```

---

Or, shorter version, without columns that don't have any value:

```
insert into ic_mst_velocity
  ( article,
    concatkey,
    lastmodifieddate,
    prodsubgrp
  ) 
  (select article,
          concatkey,
          cast(lastmodifieddate as timestamp) as lastmod,
          prodsubgrp
   from ic_velocity_v
  );
```

---

Will any of those work? I don't know; it depends on e.g.

- if there are `NOT NULL` columns but you don't put anything in there, it'll fail
- if there's a database trigger which handles that, it won't fail
- if there's uniqueness enforced and it is violated, it'll fail

  - maybe you need the `where` clause, then?
- etc.

As I said: it just *depends*.